# How to write a code to operate repeatative login and logout for multiple credentials using Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I want to have the following functionality in robot framework(RIDE)
1: Login with a set of User name and Pwd
2: Logout
3: Login with another set of User name and Pwd and so on......

I have tried following codes, but it did not work

```
${users}    Create List    apratim chaudhuri    abcd 1234
${passwords}    Create List    password1    password2
${logins}    Evaluate    [val for pair in zip(${users}, ${passwords}) for val in pair]
: FOR    ${users}    ${passwords}    IN    @{logins}
\    Log    userName: ${users} password: ${passwords}
open browser    ${url}    chrome
SeleniumLibrary.Input Text    id=userName    ${users}
input text    id=password    ${passwords}
Click Button    class=loginButton
SeleniumLibrary.Click Link    link=Logout
Click Button    xpath=//*[@id="ng-app"]/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/button[1]
Continue
```

After running the above code, only I am able to login with abcd 1234 and getting logged out. But as per my expectation, it was not picking up another set of credentials for login again.

I am new to Robotframework... Please help

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably be better served with a dictionary user/pass but i think your problem is with your loop.

```
${users}    Create List    apratim chaudhuri    abcd 1234
${passwords}    Create List    password1    password2
${logins}    Evaluate    [val for pair in zip(${users}, ${passwords}) for val in pair]

: FOR    ${user}    ${password}    IN    @{logins}
\    Log    userName: ${user} password: ${password}
\    open browser    ${url}    chrome
\    SeleniumLibrary.Input Text    id=userName    ${user}
\    input text    id=password    ${password}
\    Click Button    class=loginButton
\    SeleniumLibrary.Click Link    link=Logout
\    Click Button    xpath=//*[@id="ng-app"]/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/button[1]
\    Do Some Stuff
\    Close Browser
```